# How to import circular imports

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

app.py:

```
 def app():
     ........
```

test.py:

```
 from app import app
 def test():
      ......
```

but when I try to import " test" function in app.py file I am getting " Module error"
how can I solve this circular imports error?

Comment: You cannot have circular imports. Full stop. You must change your design for the import structure to be a direct tree without any loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a simple import, it worked without any Module error:

```
import app

def test():
     print('b')

app.app()
```

If the problem persist maybe is because is not finding the module in the directory, try on adding it in the sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/module')
```

Comment: Did this answer fix your problem @sukumar kumar?